# How to delete all workspaces in Perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce

How do I remove a workspace in Windows, using the `p4` command?

I tried the `-d` option; it says client deleted, but when I do `p4 info`, the workspace is still there. I'm using p4v as well and am not sure if that's the problem.

Or if anyone knows how to reset the whole thing (like with SVN, you just delete all .svn folders), please let me know as well.

---

My question is similar to [How to delete a workspace in Perforce (using p4v)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265915/how-to-delete-a-workspace-in-perforce-using-p4v), but not quite the same. \

Answer (score 3):

I think that 'p4 client -d' successfully deleted your workspace. 'p4 info' is just showing you the **name** of the workspace, which is set using 'p4 set P4CLIENT'. Run 'p4 clients' to see the list of all known workspaces and confirm that your workspace has successfully been deleted.